# Select statement with columns that are select statement but not subqueries

Tags: sql, syntax-highlighting, sql-server-2019, blackbaud

SQL Masters,

I don't understand part of this query. In the select statement there are what look like independent 'select statements'almost like a function. This code is vendor written Blackbaud CRM. As independent code there is no join in the code for the info they bring into the data set as you can see in the from clause. One last odd item is that in the column aliased Spouse_id the column SPOUSE.RECIPROCALCONSTITUENTID dose not even exist in the table referred to. Any BBCRM people out there that can explain this?

Thanks

```sql
    select
        CONSTITUENT.ID,
        CONSTITUENT.ISORGANIZATION,
        CONSTITUENT.KEYNAME,
        CONSTITUENT.FIRSTNAME,
        CONSTITUENT.MIDDLENAME,
        CONSTITUENT.MAIDENNAME,
        CONSTITUENT.NICKNAME,
        (select SPOUSE.RECIPROCALCONSTITUENTID 
         from dbo.RELATIONSHIP as SPOUSE 
         where SPOUSE.RELATIONSHIPCONSTITUENTID = CONSTITUENT.ID 
           and SPOUSE.ISSPOUSE = 1) as [SPOUSE_ID],
        (select MARITALSTATUSCODE.DESCRIPTION 
         from dbo.MARITALSTATUSCODE 
         where MARITALSTATUSCODE.ID = CONSTITUENT.MARITALSTATUSCODEID) as [MARITALSTATUSCODEID_TRANSLATION]
    From 
        dbo.constituent
    left join 
        dbo.ORGANIZATIONDATA on ORGANIZATIONDATA.ID = CONSTITUENT.ID
    where 
       (CONSTITUENT.ISCONSTITUENT = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

These are *correlated subqueries*.  Although there is no explicit `JOIN`, there is a link to the outer table which behaves like a join (although more constrained than explicit `JOIN`s):

```
(select SPOUSE.RECIPROCALCONSTITUENTID 
 from dbo.RELATIONSHIP as SPOUSE 
 where SPOUSE.RELATIONSHIPCONSTITUENTID = CONSTITUENT.ID AND
-------^ correlation clause connecting to outer table
       SPOUSE.ISSPOUSE = 1
) as [SPOUSE_ID],
```

This behaves like a `LEFT JOIN`.  If no rows match, then the result is `NULL`.

Note that in this context, the correlated subquery is also a *scalar subquery*.  That means that it returns exactly one column and at most one row.

If the query returned more than one column, you would get a compile-time error on the query.  If the query returns more than one row, you will get a run-time error on the query.